# Different Launch Image iPhone 6 and iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, xib, iphone-6

iPhone 4 and iPhone 6, when using image cassettes in a xib, use the same @2x image. Is it possible to use different images for each and not use scaled mode for windows 6/6+? I am trying to use a full screen image for each and the iPhone 6 image doesn't scale down correctly, and the iPhone 4 image doesn't scale up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the launch image you can use the assets folder with the device specific launch images.

[image]

Here you can set the Retina HD 4.7 Launchscreen for the iPhone 6

- 1x = 320 x 480
- 2x = 640 x 960 - iPhone 4
- Retina 4 = 640 x 1136 - iPhone 5
- Retina HD 4.7 = 750 x 1334 - iPhone 6
- Retina HD 5.5 = 1242 x 2208 - iPhone 6+

### EDIT

**Go to the General Settings Of your project and check your settings make sure you have selected the assets folder. Remove the Launch Screen File text.**

[image]

Comment: yea but you have to specify a launch screen file (xib) to tell iPhone 6/6+ to render native and not scaled. to which i can't figure out how to use the "launch image" within the xib (IB just shows a big blue question mark)...

Comment: @crizzwald Oh! If blue big question mark then the image is not available. Please check your assets

Comment: @crizzwald and you don't need xib to configure this launchscreen just add it in the general settings that you are using the assets files

Comment: that doesn't work, at least for me. I added the launch image images and hit run for the iPhone 6 simulator, the @2x image is shown and scaled on iPhone 6, not the Retina HD 4.7 image. so i add the launch screen xib, set the launch screen file setting and hit run, then the xib is shown, not the launch image.

Comment: I tried that - doesn't work. The launch image that is rendered is the @2x (the one iPhone 4(s) would use as it's launch image), not the Retina HD 4.7.

Comment: @crizzwald Make sure that you have added all image with perfect resolutions. don't use just 1x , 2x and 3x.

Comment: yup, that was it. I had the wrong image size in the 4.7 slot. I mistakenly grabbed the wrong image. thanks for you help.

Comment: @crizzwald Welcome anytime :)